# MVC3 Url.Action() - Is there a simpiler way to write links in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on a site and I'm new to MVC3 Framework. I'm coming from a place where writing URL's is very simple `href="some/web/page.html"` but now with the MVC3 URLs are more complex.

By complex I mean are more involved to write. `href="@Url.Action("index", "Home")"` that requires hitting the shift key multiple times which is tiresome and redundant for someone coming from `href="some/web/page.html"` only hitting shift twice for that.

And the site I'm working on is using areas which adds another level of complexity to the URL.

```
href="@Url.Action("index", "area", new { area = "some_area})"
```

I'm working on a 100+ page site. Writing these `@Action.Url()` is becoming boring and irritating. Is there something I can do to cut out the redundancy?

Comment: Have you had a look at T4MVC? Using the extension methods from there will cut these down to `@Url.Action(MVC.Areas.SomeArea.Area.Index())` and with intellisense and compile time warning too when areas, controllers or actions are renamed.

Comment: I have not seen that. It does seem interesting I may test it out in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make some extension methods like Kazi explains here : 
http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/01/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-1.aspx

Something like this :

```
public static class UrlHelperExtension
{
    public static string Home(this UrlHelper helper)
    {
        return helper.Content("~/");
    }
}
```

You can also use David Ebbo MVC T4 template for generating helper methods :
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2009/06/01/a-buildprovider-to-simplify-your-asp-net-mvc-action-links.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2009/06/26/the-mvc-t4-template-is-now-up-on-codeplex-and-it-does-change-your-code-a-bit.aspx

http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC_doc&referringTitle=T4MVC

Hope this helps

Comment: I like the first method you show. I think it will work well since I am just learning MVC and C# then maybe down the line I will use something like MVC T4 once I'm comfortable using the languages and have a good base with them.

Comment: I did the first method. However there is an issue. I don't have access to the helpers inside Partial Views. This is where I would make the most use of of them example: _PartialHeader, _PartialFooter where my main navigation is stored. Is there an extra step to make them available in Partial Views?

Comment: Disregard the last comment. I needed to rebuild my solution. It's working now

Answer (score 3):

You could try using [**T4MVC**](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC), other than that there isn't really much you can do.

You can read it's documentation [here](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC_doc&referringTitle=T4MVC).

Comment: Giving you an up-vote because that link points to a URL that shows T4MVC has been moved 4 different times since you posted this. :)  Seriously though, Microsoft needs to bake this into MVC instead of making devs write string literals in the Url.Action() helper. That was fine for MVC beta, but let's move on and get those strongly typed.